# grep pattern for column names

Tags: r, regex

I have a data frame and want to grep column names that fit particular patterns. I have four sets of patterns:

```
# set 1 (underscore, no A)
  cat1_1
  cat12_12

# set 2 (underscore, A)
  cat4_4A
  cat18_18A

# set 3 (no underscore, no p)
  dog2
  dog12

# set 4 (no underscore, p)
  dog2p
  dog12p
```

My actual data frame contains different numbers of columns per set, but I am showing just two columns per set in this example for simplicity.

```
ex <- data.frame(cat1_1=c("1a", "1a"),
                 cat12_12=c("1b", "1b"),
                 cat4_4A=c("2a", "2a"),
                 cat18_18A=c("2b", "2b"),
                 dog2=c("3a", "3a"),
                 dog12=c("3b", "3b"),
                 dog2p=c("4a", "4a"),
                 dog12p=c("4b", "4c"))
ex
#      cat1_1 cat12_12 cat4_4A cat18_18A dog2 dog12 dog2p dog12p
#1     1a       1b      2a        2b   3a    3b    4a     4b
#2     1a       1b      2a        2b   3a    3b    4a     4c
```

I want to grep `names(ex)` so that I grab all set 1 variables, then separately, all set 2 variables, and so on. So for instance, `grep(PATTERN, names(ex))` for set 1 should return:

`[1] "cat1_1"   "cat12_12"`

I'd appreciate help with the grep pattern for each set. One constraint is that I do not want to change any column names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the example showed by the OP, if we need to find patterns in the colnames, that start (`^`) with 'cat' followed by one or more numbers (`\\d+`) followed by an underscore (`\\_`) followed by one or more numbers ('\d+') till the end of the string (`$`), we get 'cat1_1', 'cat12_12'.

```
 grep('^cat\\d+\\_\\d+$', names(ex), value=TRUE)
```

Similar logic can be used for the other cases.

```
 grep('^cat\\d+\\_\\d+[A-Z]+$', names(ex), value= TRUE)
 grep('^dog\\d+$', names(ex), value=TRUE)
 grep('^dog\\d+[a-z]+$', names(ex), value=TRUE)
```

---

Or another option would be to `split` the column names by creating a grouping variable based on `names(ex)`

```
 split(names(ex), gsub('\\d+(?=\\_)|(?<=\\_)\\d+|(?<=[a-z])\\d+', 
                             '1', names(ex), perl=TRUE))
 #$cat1_1
 #[1] "cat1_1"   "cat12_12"

 #$cat1_1A
 #[1] "cat4_4A"   "cat18_18A"

 #$dog1
 #[1] "dog2"  "dog12"

 #$dog1p
 #[1] "dog2p"  "dog12p"
```

Comment: thanks, @akrun! if you would not mind, could you explain the logic behind the first two? hopefully i'll be able to use this example to generalize to other situations.

Comment: wonderful. this is very clear. i really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the begins with `^` and ends with `$` [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html):

```
names(ex)[grep("^cat.*[0-9]$", names(ex))]

names(ex)[grep("^cat.*A$", names(ex))]

names(ex)[grep("^dog.*[0-9]$", names(ex))]

names(ex)[grep("^dog.*p$", names(ex))]
```

Comment: I don't think the `[]` around `cat` and `dog` are necessary, are they?

Answer (score 0):

As an amendment to the good answers thus far, R has some "special" strings that might ease the transition into using regular expressions.  For example, `[:digit:]` will match any numerical value and `[:alpha:]` will match any alphabetical character.

If we apply this to the four column name types that you are working with we get the following:

```
grep("^cat[[:digit:]]+_[[:digit:]]+$", names(ex), value=TRUE)
# "cat1_1"   "cat12_12"

grep("^cat[[:digit:]]+_[[:digit:]]+A$", names(ex), value=TRUE)
# "cat4_4A"   "cat18_18A"

grep("^dog[[:digit:]]+$", names(ex), value=TRUE)
# "dog2"  "dog12"

grep("^dog[[:digit:]]+p$", names(ex), value=TRUE)
# "dog2p"  "dog12p"
```

Note that we have to enclose `[:digit:]` in another set of square brackets to properly delineate the range of values it represents, but at the very least I think it's a bit more readable to a newcomer than double escape characters such `\\d` (although at some point you'll get tired of typing the extra characters :D).

For a complete list of these "special" strings and other useful information about regular expressions in R, I would recommend checking out [this link](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) from the R base documentation.